# Wordpress, remove everything before a specific character

Tags: php

I need to remove everything before a specific character in Wordpress Title

I already tried different codes i found here but i couldnt get it working
i need something like this

```
echo strstr(get_the_title(),"-",true);
```

or

```
echo $str = 'get_the_title()';
$str = substr($str, 0, strpos($str, '-'));
```

The first code just outputs the normal Title

On the second im not sure how i can run a php code instead of normal characters.

Update:

I got it working now thanks to harryg & jrod

```
$str = get_the_title(); //This would be your post title (get_the_title)
$char =  " - "; //Define the separator
$strpos = strpos($str, $char); //Find out where it occurs
$str = substr($str, $strpos+strlen($char)); //Extract the substring after the separator
echo $str;
```

for some reason wordpress conversates my hpyhen to a en-dash so i added it

```
remove_filter( 'the_title', 'wptexturize' );
```

to my funtions.php and it worked. Maybe it helps someone in the future. Thanks for all answers!

Comment: If you are using `strstr` you are going to want to set the third parameter to `false` to get everything after your specific character. Setting it to `true` returns everything before the needle excluding the needle.  In your second example you should echo your second line not your first and get rid of the quotes around `get_the_title`.  For further assistance please provide the title you are working with.

Comment: `code` echo $str = get_the_title();
$str = substr($str, 0, strpos($str, '–'));  ok this works but it just outputs the normal title..The title is always different it just has always a "-" in it. Everything before the "-" is what i want to have removed

Comment: Where are you running this code from?  A template file?  If so, are you sure that template file is being run? Providing an example title would allow someone like myself to test your code and help debug it.  If I run your code and get different results you may have another problem altogether.

Comment: Im running the code in a custom single.php im already running a similar code and its working fine `code`strtolower(preg_replace('/[^\p{L}]/u', " ", get_the_title()));?>, <?php echo strtolower(preg_replace('/[^\p{L}]/u', " ", get_the_title())); `code`

Comment: Just drop those apostrophes in your second example. Apostrophes are for strings. You want to call a function, not to quote its name.

Comment: already tried it doenst work

Comment: Can we see one of the pages in question?  It is possible the hyphen is not a hyphen.

Comment: hmm maybe you are right, i mean i type the hyphen myself but when i copy&paste it here directly from the page "–" it looks not like the hyphen i type myself "-" right?

Answer (score 0):

This should do it...

```
$str = "this comes before - this comes after"; //This would be your post title (get_the_title)
$char =  " - "; //Define the separator
$strpos = strpos($str, $char); //Find out where it occurs
$str = substr($str, $strpos+strlen($char)); //Extract the substring after the separator
echo $str; //Result will be "this comes after"
```

Please bear in mind that `$char` will need to exactly match the separator that occurs in your title. If it is html-encoded (e.g. `&mdash;` for an em-dash) you will need to use the html entity as the separator. It will also trim the start of the title upon the *first* instance of the separator. If you have multiple occurrences of the separator you will need to adjust the code depending on where in your title they occur.

Comment: the output is also just the normal title

Comment: `code` $str = get_the_title();
$char =  " - ";
$strpos = strpos($str, $char);
$str = substr($str, $strpos+strlen($char)); its almost close but it just removethe first 2 letters beofre the "-"
echo $str;?>

Comment: still the same it just removes 2 letters. like: Normal title: Hello - Hello goes to: llo - Hello

Comment: ok i see this is working with normal letters but first of all i need to call the title to get it. The title is always different its the Wordpress Post Title

Comment: Yes, you need to define `$str = get_post_title();` as mentioned in my comments

Comment: yes i know i tried it  `$str = get_the_title();` but like i said it just removes 2 letters before the character

Comment: It is because the separator I defined originally is `" - "` (i.e. there is a space either side of the dash). If your separator has no space, or only has a space on one side the code will not find it. Redefine the `$char` variable to what appears in your title.

Comment: im sorry its removing always 3 letters

Comment: ok the more spaces i add to the `$char` the more letters are getting removed. But its not really helpful cause the title length is always different

Comment: It's because it's not finding the separator. You need to ensure the `$char` variable exactly matches the separator that occurs in your post title. It removes the first 3 character as it takes the substring of the title starting at `length of $char + point where $char occurs`. Copy and paste the separator as the $char if you are unsure, I feel it could be because one is an m-dash and the other in an n-dash. If you have a page you are working on it would help to paste the link.

Comment: yes harry you are right i already edited my post on top and posted the working solution..many many thanks

Comment: Great, if you feel my solution answered your question then it'd be great if you clicked the tick to accept it as the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `preg_replace` for this:

```
$str = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet - consetetur sadipscing elitr'; // your title
$sep =  ' - '; // separator
$short = preg_replace('/^(.*?)'.$sep.'(.*)$/si', '$2', $str, 1); // your short title
echo $short; // result: "consetetur sadipscing elitr"
```

This will replace all characters before the **first** occurrence of your separator. In case the separator exists multiple times in `$str` and you want to replace everything before the **last** occurrence of the separator use:

```
$short = preg_replace('/^(.*)'.$sep.'(.*)$/si', '$2', $str, 1); // your short title
```

Keep in mind, that if you use special characters in `$sep` you have to escape them.

Comment: it doesnt work the output is the normal title `$str = get_the_title(); 
$sep =  ' - '; // separator
$short = preg_replace('/^(.*?)'.$sep.'(.*)$/si', '$2', $str, 1); 
echo $short;`

Comment: Are you sure that you are using the correct separator? Sure that's `<space><minus><space>`? Try `echo urlencode($str);`. If you see an output like `+-+` at the position of the separator then it should work. If you see something like `+%E2%80%92+` your separator is a special char (dash, ...).

Comment: you are right it got conversate from hyphen to a en-dash..i already edited the post on top and posted the working solution..thanks so much

Answer (score -1):

`$char="enter the character before which you want to delete the connect here";

$str =get_the_title();
$substr = explode($char,$str);
echo $substr[1];`

by using explode function you can break the string to array with a particular charcter

Comment: this outputs just the character and removes everything before and after

Comment: then please send the title and please send the character before which you want to delete everything]

Comment: The title is always different it just always includes the "-" character and everything before the "-" needs to be removed. Thats the code how i get the title `code` get_the_title()

Comment: Exploding a string just to trim it isn't a good idea. And array indexes are zero-based, so this code won't work as expected.