# Wordpress : Remove everything after a specific character

Tags: php, wordpress

So there is a good example on how to remove everything *before* specific character, but I'm looking for opposite... after a specific character, in the WordPress title field.

What I have:
A WordPress title - stuff I want to delete

What I want:
A WordPress title

I've experimented with the code (which is almost exactly what I want to do) in this example [Wordpress, remove everything before a specific character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14858732/wordpress-remove-everything-before-a-specific-character) but I'm doing something wrong with my code! And yes I added the code to the functions.php file to recognize the dash as the special character.

Thanks!

Comment: reverse the string and remove everything before the character?

Comment: Your linked example should have worked already. It's perhaps that the title is a different string then you expect.

Answer (score 1):

Simple. [Explode](http://php.net/explode) on the delimiter, use the parts of the array.

```
$parts = explode(' - ', get_the_title(), 2);
$before = $parts[0]; //before the - 
$after = $parts[1]; //after the -
```

because you're discussing `the_title` and Wordpress, I'm going to provide the integration as a filter as well:

```
function explode_parts($title, $id){
    $parts = explode(' - ', $title);
    $before = $parts[0]; //before the - 
    $after = $parts[1]; //after the - 
    return (whatever);
}

add_filter('the_title', 'explode_parts');
```

Make sure to add a conditional statement so that the function is only executed on titles that you wish to perform this operation on.

Comment: Thanks for helping. Unfortunately, the title gets replaced with a 'missing argument 2 in explode_parts' error...